# como mover botones de ruta en la pagina angular 8/9

Tags: html, angular, web, aplicación-web

tengo el siguiente codigo simple, es una pagina que tiene 2 botones (ir a formularios) y (ir a resultados) los cuales nos llevan a las rutas /formularios y /test, necesito ahora hacerlo un poco mas agradable a la vista, agregar un background y centrar los botones, como puedo hacer esto? adjuntare fotos de los codigos

1. la foto con el punto verde es el app.component.html, donde llamo al componente header con su respectiva etiqueta (el cual tiene dentro los 2 botones que llevan a las rutas) y el router outlet que permite ver el contenido de estas ventanas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. la foto con el punto rojo es el header.html donde tengo ubicado los enlaces de las rutas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. la ultima foto es lo que seria el "home" de mi pagina, donde ahi se puede ver el lugar que estan ubicados los 2 botones, me gustaria poder centrarlos y tambien poner un background para que no este el fondo blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar CSS para agregar un background y centrar los botones. Si quieres un background para todo la app, usa el estilo `background` o `background-color` en app.component.css.

Ejemplo:

```
background-color: blue;
```

Para centrar los botones, hay mucha opciones. Yo prefiero `flex`.

Ejemplo:

```css
.centrar-botones {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centrar-botones">
    <a>link 1</a>
    <a>link 2</a>
</div>
```